# Add JSON data to an array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json

Hello I am new to JavaScript and I have been trying to parse JSON data into a JavaScript array. I can load the local .json file and print it to the console. I want to print each 'key' and 'value' pair. Having come from a python background, this is new to me. This is a sample JSON data. The structure of the data I want to use is the same. I am mostly having trouble because of the strucure of the JSON data. I have to control to change the structure of the JSON data

```
{
    "emp_details":[
    {
        "emp_name":["abc"],
        "email":["abc@email.com"],
        "job_profile":["Full time"]
    }
    
    ]
}
```

And here is what I have done. Which is just read the local file and print it to the console.

```
function readTextFile(file, callback) {
    var rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
    rawFile.overrideMimeType("application/json");
    rawFile.open("GET", file, true);
    rawFile.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (rawFile.readyState === 4 && rawFile.status == "200") {
            callback(rawFile.responseText);
        }
    }
    rawFile.send(null);
}

readTextFile("./data.json",function(text){
    var data = JSON.parse(text);
    var dataArray = []
    dataArray.push(data)    
    //alert(data);
    console.log(dataArray[0]);
});
```

Ideally I want the result to be like to display in an HTML table:

| emp_name | email | job_profile |
| --- | --- | --- |
| abc | abc@email.com | Full time |

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that you already have defined HTML table named `emp_table`, so in that case, you can get desired output by following code: -

```
const empTable = document.getElementById('emp_table');

empTable.innerHTML = json.emp_details.map((emp) =>
  Object.keys(emp).map(
    (key) =>
      `<tr><td><label><strong>${key}</strong><label></td><td>${emp[key][0]}</td></tr>`
  )
);
```

Comment: Can you tell me what emp is here?

Comment: emp is referring to each employee in the map iteration @doryfied

Answer (score 0):

You can use [console.table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console/table) to print tabular data.

```js
let data = {
  "emp_details": [
    {
      "emp_name": ["abc"],
      "email": ["abc@email.com"],
      "job_profile": ["Full time"]
    },
    {
      "emp_name": ["def"],
      "email": ["def@email.com"],
      "job_profile": ["Full time"]
    }
  ]
}

// convert the array in each property to a string
let emp_details = data["emp_details"].map(function(employee) {
  return {
    emp_name: employee.emp_name[0],
    email: employee.email[0],
    job_profile: employee.job_profile[0],
  }
});

// print the data in a table
console.table(emp_details)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a table in your html file with an id of table:

```
<table id="table"></table>
```

And then use a nested for loop to iterate through the data by doing something like this:

```
readTextFile("./data.json", function(text) {
    var data = JSON.parse(text);
    var dataArray = data.emp_details;
    var table = document.getElementById("table");

    for (var i = 0; i < dataArray.length; i++) {
        var row = table.insertRow();

        for (var key in dataArray[i]) {
            var cell1 = row.insertCell();
            var cell2 = row.insertCell();

            cell1.innerHTML = key;
            cell2.innerHTML = dataArray[i][key];
        }
    }
});
```

The first for loop iterates through the emp_details array, and the second for loop iterates through each object in the array.

The key and value of each object is then inserted into a new row in the table, with the key in the first cell and the value in the second cell.

Comment: How can I use the key as the column header and values as the row entries? I know it is not the original question but can you please help me out?